# SSRS 2016 Issues

Tags: reporting-services, permissions, ssrs-2016

Our IT Dept gave me an ***SSRS 2016 Dev Instance*** to play with. But I have two things that I need to figure out, as I've hit a dead end on:

- The `AppId` I need to run our subscriptions under. It's needed to be setup on the ***SSRS Server*** to allow Local Login or the reports *would not work*.

  - Can some explain why we would need to allow login locally? Or even if it's the correct way to handle it, or should I be setting up something different for the AppId to work correctly?
- I also need to be able to setup shared schedules. However when I click the settings gear, I only have ***'My Subscriptions'***, and I understand I need ***'Site Settings'*** to show up here.

  - What permissions do they need to setup in order for me to gain access to Site Settings?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, I'm not sure how to answer the first one. I think because SSRS is an additional service external of SQL Server it needs a local SQL Server login. Not really my forte.

By default there is a BUILTIN\Administrators role. The following link will describe who gets placed in the BUILTIN\Administrators role. Once you're in there, you can get to site settings and add your own security settings and shared schedules.

[BUILTIN\Administrators info link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/f02f0b2e-16a9-42a9-b956-01e3b114732a/which-users-are-part-of-builtinadministrators?forum=tfsadmin)

Hope this helps.